# Disable unused IPs on network

Tags: iptables, ip-address

I want to force people to use the DHCP server for my network. I have a set of static IPs reserved but not all of them are used. How can I prevent people from setting one of these IPs as a static IP?

Basically I want to prevent people from using Static IPs unless I authorize it. I use DD-WRT for my home router.

The reason I want to block people from using static IPs is because those IPs are authorized to access the network infrastructure.

Comment: You can't; MAC addressing whitelisting is the obvious solution but the problem with that is spoofing your MAC address is trivial

Comment: I think its better to take a look at your own infrastructure. If a user can just change his IP to a different IP and then have access to a different network. Then your infrastructure is far from secure.

Comment: @DylanRz I've seen some businesses accomplish what I'm trying here I believe. I believe they use managed switches to route all unused IPs to an empty port. Is there a consumer-grade equivalent? Or am I completely wrong about how they go about doing this. I've reconfigured the network so there are separate subnets for guest users but I would still like to restrict the use of static IPs unless I authorize it.

Comment: are the static IP's from the same range or from a different range?

Comment: @DylanRz I have two networks on my router. 10.1.0.0 for the main network and 10.2.0.0 for guests. They are both completely separated and cannot talk to each other. On 10.1.0.0 the DHCP server starts at 10.1.0.51 and 10.1.0.1-50 are used for static addressing. I want to restrict people from changing their IPs to one of these addresses because they are granted access to my server infrastructure. Obviously its not too big of an issue if they somehow change their IP to one of these because you still need credentials to access any of the systems but I would like to prevent even that from happening.

Comment: Anything above 10.1.0.51 is not allowed to even talk to any of the servers.

Comment: Well what I would do is have your server infrastructure on a different network as well so say 10.3.0.0 in my case I would use 10.1.0.0 for the server network and 10.3.0.0 for the client network. This is also best practice. Its not possible to block clients from using that IP address. Sinds the switch will still send it back and forth on the same network. The dhcp server has nothing to do with it.